# How to update webapp2_extras session in GAE based application

Tags: google-app-engine, session, google-oauth, webapp2

I have two questions:

1. First one is that Is it good practice to update a session (frequently) once it has been created? If no, then what are the possible issues which could occur?
2. I am working on GAE based application and using webapp2_extras auth model provided by GAE for authentication. 
   I am trying to update the value of an attribute of session (after it has been created), but it does not seem to be working.

The exact code piece is:

```
updates = {'fullname': 'sdsdsdsdsd'}
self.auth.set_session_data(session, **updates)
```

but, it throws an error that:

```
TypeError: set_cookie() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fullname'
```

According to the documentation of the lib, it should work. As, it written that:

```
def set_session_data(self, data, **session_args):
    """Sets the session data as a list.

    :param data:
        Deserialized session data.
    :param session_args:
        Extra arguments for the session.
    """
    data = self.store.serialize_session(data)
    if data is not None:
        self.session['_user'] = data
        self.session.container.session_args.update(session_args)
```

Can anyone please help me here? Also, explains if I should be updating the session or not? I have a scenario where I will be doing that but it does not seem good to be. I think a session should not be updated manually once it has been created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be something like this:

```
self.auth.set_session_data(updates)
```

but that will wipe out any keys that are already there (like 'user_id' which is needed for the auth to work), so maybe do this instead:

```
session_data = self.auth.get_session_data()
session_data['fullname'] = 'sdsdsdsdsd'
self.auth.set_session_data(session_data)
```

I don't know what that `session` variable was that you were trying to pass in, but `set_session_data()` only set's `self.session`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It works!
However, I am still curious about the first question i.e. is it good practice to update sessions frequently or it should be avoided?
Please shed some light on this too so that I can accept your answer.

Comment: I can't think of a reason as to why that would be bad, but then again it really depends on what you are doing in these 'updates'. The only potential risk i see is the server potentially receiving stale cookies if the client failed to get your new cookies due to a timeout.